# Find attribute value using selenium <span class='overlay' title id='ab12'></span>

Tags: html, selenium, attributes

I am trying to get value of `title` attribute for following html code :-

```
<span class='overlay' title id='ab12'></span>
```

Actually this code is written for a tooltip. When i view source code for this `HTML` page , I see following

```
<span class='overlay' title="Test Tooltip"></span>
```

So basically `id='ab12'` in `HTML` code denotes `Test Tooltip`.

Could you tell me how can I get this text value (Test Tooltip) using `Selenium-Webdriver` ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question creates some confusion, I don't think what you are saying about `id='ab12'`, but as I'm seeing in your provided `HTML` `class='overlay'` is fixed.

(Assuming you're using Java) you should try using `By.className()` to locate `<span>` element, then use `getAttribute("title")` to get tooltip text as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.className("overlay"));
String tooltip  = el.getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: I do not think this will work, as mentioned in the question 'id=ab12' is only there in HTML code but not in HTML page source. You need to search for span with the class.

Comment: @Grasshopper Question creates some confusion, id may be present or not, but you are right class name is present, I have updated my answer. Thanks to point it out..:)